# Buscador por palabras clave

Tags: javascript, array

Buenos días estoy buscando una manera de optimizar mi buscador, ya que sólo busca por las primeras palabras. Por ejemplo:

Si ingreso "au" me muestra las palabras que comienzan con au, a mi me gustaria que me muestre todas las que tengan algo que ver con au, como por ejemplo mecanico de autos, etc. 
Lo que quiero es que no compare sólo las primeras palabras. Sino que por todas en donde exista..

Dejo la funcion javascript de mi buscador, en realidad sólo la parte que interesa:

```
 inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
          var a, b, i, val = this.value;
          /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
          closeAllLists();
          if (!val) { return false;}
          currentFocus = -1;
          /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
          a = document.createElement("DIV");
          a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
          a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
          /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
          this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
          /*for each item in the array...*/
          for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1);
            /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
            if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
              /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
              b = document.createElement("DIV");
              b.setAttribute("class", "ayudadorlistaporuno");
              /*make the matching letters bold:*/
              b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
              b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
```

Como allí se observa y está comentado:

```
if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {}
```

Sería la función que tenemos que modificar pero realmente hace días que no logro destrabarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier ayuda, saludos!

Comment: ¿Has probado a a usar `arr[i].toUpperCase().includes(val.toUpperCase())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el método [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf), de la forma:

```
if (arr[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) !== -1) { ... }
```

Para resaltar la parte de la cadena encontrada crea el `innerHTML` de la siguiente forma:

```
let fromIdx = arr[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase());
let toIdx = fromIdx + val.length;
b.innerHTML = arr[i].substring(0, fromIdx);
b.innerHTML += "<strong>" + arr[i].substring(fromIdx, toIdx) + "</strong>";
b.innerHTML += arr[i].substring(toIdx);
```

Comment: Eso funciona a la perfección !, pero me queda algo por resolver..
Se resaltan las primeras palabras, como podré hacer para que resalte las letras tipeadas?
Por ejemplo cuando pongo "au" aparecen bien, pero en productor del automotor se resalta solo "pr" como si hubiera escrito esa palabra.

Comment: @Juampi, he actualizado la respuesta con el resaltado

Comment: Funciona a la perfección !! muchisimas gracias por la ayuda !

Comment: Lo último que te pregunto es, como se puede hacer para que tome también las palabras sin acentos. Por ejemplo si pongo estetica sin acento aparezca "estética", como que descarte los acentos. Gracias !!

Comment: Uff, el tema de los acentos es bastante más complicado, para eso te sugiero que crees otra pregunta, la solución de esa casuistica no es evidente

Comment: Ahh si ya me parecía que se iba por otro lado.. De todas maneras quedo super óptimo, te agradezco mucho !